# What is the meaning of "I come from sturdy stock"?

Tags: phrases, phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

The sentence is followed by " and I'm all alone in the world".They may be correlative, but I can't figure out the former.Your thoughts are much appreciated.

Comment: Yep, basically it implies a family history of physical and/or emotional strength and good health.

Comment: the full phrase or two that confuse you please

Comment: are you asking : i am strong yet alone?

Answer (score 3):

When animals are bred, the healthier, sturdier specimens are chosen as breeding stock (parents).

This is a transferred usage, and may refer to the emotional stability / resilience rather than or in addition to the physical stability / strength /vitality // longevity of the speaker.

> ... I come from sturdy stock and am not expected to be 'puny' and
>   'whiny'.

[[Bloodroot: Reflections on Place by Appalachian Women Writers
edited by Joyce Dyer](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=mfYwpYrNQ0YC&pg=PT26&lpg=PT26&dq=%22I+come+from+sturdy+stock%22&source=bl&ots=IeYOBKf6qW&sig=quASWChpjnBxWFWdhGWAo1gjrj0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwijluzoh6jaAhWPSsAKHeycBl4Q6AEIMDAC#v=onepage&q=%22I%20come%20from%20sturdy%20stock%22&f=false)]